Movie about a man travelling between real life and dreams to fix his problems then loses track of reality
I was in a movie theatre around 4-5 years ago, ready to watch a film in the USA (I don't remember which film it was, but it was PG-13 if that helps). Then I saw a trailer for a remarkable movie, and I've wanted to watch it ever since.
The movie described the life of this businessman who had a lot of problems in his work, and these problems were really weighing down on him. If I remember correctly, he was facing a very large corporate problem for which he could find no solution. But he had a solid relationship with his wife and family - basically, his personal life was loving and excellent.
One day, the man falls asleep, and in his sleep, his dream is (sort of) like his entrance into this parallel world where his life is flipped - his business life is going great, but his personal life is crap. The whole movie is essentially about this guy taking ideas from said parallel world into his real life to fix his business problems, and he takes ideas from his real life into this parallel world to fix his personal problems. 
But he does it too much, and he can no longer distinguish between dreams and reality. He doesn't know when he is dreaming and when he is in this parallel world. That's sort of how the trailer ends, so I don't know much more detail. But it sounded like a really interesting movie... if any of you guys know the title, could you tell me? I remember a week or so later I started scouring all websites for movies to be released in the upcoming years to remember the name of that movie... Nada. Nothing. But I swear I saw that trailer! 
Thanks for the help.

Reminiscent of The Family Man, but kind of in reverse (and there's very little chance you saw the trailer 5 years ago, it's from 2000).

@Walt I just saw the trailer to be sure, and no, it isn't it :( Am I never to find this movie?!

A bit similar to Awake but don't quite match and it's a tv show.

Do you remember what film you went to see? Might narrow down the year.

@tohood87 no :( I know it was an action movie... think something like avengers (it definitely wasnt avengers)

Sounds like 2013's The Secret Life of Walter Mitty starring Ben Stiller as an office worker whose boring life is shaken up by fantastic travels:

When his job along with that of his co-worker are threatened, Walter takes action in the real world embarking on a global journey that turns into an adventure more extraordinary than anything he could have ever imagined.

Here's the trailer to help confirm if this is your movie. And here's one of the posters:


Thanks for the suggestion, but this is definitely not it :(

There's no way it's Inception, right? It came out in 2010 so I'm doubtful, but just in case here's the trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hP9D6kZseM

Is it possible it was an ad for a TV show? My local movie theaters often show ads or trailers for TV shows. The 2012 TV show Awake has a similar premise:

After a car accident takes the life of a family member, a police detective lives two alternating parallel lives, one with his wife and one with his son. Is one of his "realities" merely a dream?

